# connect to mysql database on my home computer from college

Tags: mysql, connection

I am a freshman in computer science, so bear with me. sorry.

I have installed MySQL on my windows 7 machine. Installed are Server/Workbench/Utilities/Shell/Router

I have created a test database (schema?) and called it test. I have been able to use the shell (just put password in) to run some commands to verify I am creating some test tables and stuff. I have also been able to use Workbench to access what I have created. It says "Local instance MY SQL Router / root / localhost:3306"

Now that is all very well and good. But how do I access this database (or is it server?? I don't know what my server is called) I have created on my home computer from college computers?

my college computer labs will also have MySQL workbench. I will be keep home computer on if I want to access it from campus.

Comment: Is your home computer is assigned with a real ip? If not then this is not possible.

Comment: If you do not have a fixed Ip address for your internet connection, you can use dynamic DNS services on the web. Then you have to open your router, firewall and PC to allow connections on that port.

Comment: well, technically, i can always use teamviewer to remote access my desktop and find out what its ip address is at that very moment. I just don't know how to start logging in from another mysql workbench on another computer. the only purpose of accessing my database remotely is so I can do some work at home and access it on campus if I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you use a router at home, with a firewall. Otherwise your home system will quickly get pwned by hackers. I once turned on logging on my firewall to show me how often I was being probed by illicit requests looking for vulnerabilities. I had to turn off the log because it was taking up too much space after a few hours.

Your router will also need to be configured to forward requests to your Windows PC, because the public IP address is just for the router itself. The individual PC's on your home network are all hidden behind that router using NAT. So they each have an internal IP address like 192.168.0.110, but clients from the outside world can't reach that.

So you need to tell the router that when requests come in (at least for the specific port 3306 for MySQL), then forward that to your PC on 192.168.0.110 (or whatever IP address it has been assigned by your router). You should read the manual on your router to find out how to do this, because it's different in every brand of router.

Your Windows PC also has a firewall. It undoubtedly blocks the MySQL port 3306 by default. You will need to allow incoming requests on that port. See https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html

Frankly, I wouldn't like to do any of this, because it opens up too much security that I'd like to keep shut. The MySQL protocol isn't designed to be perfectly secure, so allowing remote clients to connect risks allowing attackers into your home computer.

Instead, I would recommend to run MySQL Server on a cloud server like Digital Ocean. Then you can access the same cloud server from either your home PC or from clients at school. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql

A small Digital Ocean instance that can run MySQL Server costs $5 or $10/month. Not so much compared to a single college textbook. See https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/